# MongoDB - How to get last month records

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How can I fetch last month's records in MongoDB?

Following is the MYSQL query used to do the same:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE YEAR(createdon) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND MONTH(createdon) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1: `$where` operator for `db.collection.find()`

*Supported version: **Before 4.4***

You can use [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) which is supported with Javascript `function()`.

```
db.collection.find({
  $where: function() { 
    var currentDate = new Date(); 
    var lastMonthDate = new Date(currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() - 1)); 

    return this.createdOn.getFullYear() === lastMonthDate.getFullYear() 
      && this.createdOn.getMonth() === lastMonthDate.getMonth(); 
  }
})
```

*Note:
Wrap the function with the quotes in Mongo Playground is due to [reported Github issue](https://github.com/feliixx/mongoplayground/issues/62).*

[Sample Solution 1 on Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MFz0cW58R2v)

---

### Solution 2: With `$dateAdd` for `db.collection.aggregate()`

*Supported version: **5.0***

With [`$dateAdd`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateAdd/) is introduced in version 5.0, you can perform the query as below:

1. `$match`:

   - With `$match` pipeline, using `$expr` query expression to include the aggregation operation.
   - `$and` operator to ensure both expressions are fulfilled.
   - Using `$dateAdd` operator to add month (unit) by -1 (amount) to get *previous month date*.
   - `$month` and `$year` are for getting the month and year value from date respectively.
   - And perform `$eq` operator to check both `$month` and `$year` from `createdOn` are matched with both `$month` and `$year` from *previous month date* respectively.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            "$eq": [
              {
                $month: "$createdOn"
              },
              {
                $month: {
                  $dateAdd: {
                    startDate: new Date(),
                    unit: "month",
                    amount: -1
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "$eq": [
              {
                $year: "$createdOn"
              },
              {
                $year: {
                  $dateAdd: {
                    startDate: new Date(),
                    unit: "month",
                    amount: -1
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Solution 2 on Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Coint6X88uw)

---

### Solution 3: With `$dateFromParts` for `db.collection.aggregate()`

*Supported version: **From 3.6***

You may also apply with [`$dateFromParts`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/) which is suggested by this [Jira comment](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10651?focusedCommentId=2305913&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-2305913).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            "$eq": [
              {
                $month: "$createdOn"
              },
              {
                $month: {
                  $let: {
                    "vars": {
                      "todayDate": new Date()
                    },
                    "in": {
                      $dateFromParts: {
                        year: {
                          $year: "$$todayDate"
                        },
                        month: {
                          $subtract: [
                            {
                              $month: "$$todayDate"
                            },
                            1
                          ]
                        },
                        day: {
                          $dayOfMonth: "$$todayDate"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "$eq": [
              {
                $year: "$createdOn"
              },
              {
                $year: {
                  $let: {
                    "vars": {
                      "todayDate": new Date()
                    },
                    "in": {
                      $dateFromParts: {
                        year: {
                          $year: "$$todayDate"
                        },
                        month: {
                          $subtract: [
                            {
                              $month: "$$todayDate"
                            },
                            1
                          ]
                        },
                        day: {
                          $dayOfMonth: "$$todayDate"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Solution 3 on Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7C7C9KXgQmF)

Comment: Hey Yong, Thanks for your reply but I'm using version 4.4 and it doesn't the function. Can you please suggest a query in the lower version? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, added Solution 3 with `$dateFromParts`.

Comment: Does the solution 3 account for the scenario where the month is January and subtracting 1 should roll the year back to the previous year?

Comment: @KarthicRaghupathi Yes, MongoDB will handle for it. For your reference: [Value is Less than the Range](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/#value-is-less-than-the-range)

Answer (score 1):

You can select the records between two dates using the $gte and $lte options. Example:

```
db.getCollection('your-collection-name').find({
  {createdAt:{$gte:ISODate(“2020-03-01”),$lt:ISODate(“2021-03-31”)}}
})
```

more information about these operators:

- $lte -> https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/
- $gte -> https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, but I want it dynamically means I have a field  "createdon" and want last month record from the "createdon" month.