# Get MongoDB records of the last day in the previous month

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

I've a MongoDB collection that contains records with a field called **createdAt**, I want to get the last createdAt in the previous month of a given date using mongoTemplate aggregation in a spring boot application.

example of a record:

```json
{
  createdAt: new Date('2022-11-01'), 
  //other fields ...
}
```

**Note:**

Let say for 22/11/2022 given date, and we have records with createdAt fields are 12/10/2022, 22/10/2022, 27/10/2022; I wanna get the date : 27/10/2022

Comment: You want to retrieve an unknown number of records that all have the same `createdAt` value which may not be the last day of the previous month?

Comment: I want to retrieve the last available createdAt date, having the month as the previous month of a given date. let say for 22/11/2022 given date, and we have records with createdAt fields are : 12/10/2022,   22/10/2022,   27/10/2022; I wanna get the date : 27/10/2022

Answer (score 1):

if you are using mongo template you could find it like this:

```
template.aggregate(
                        newAggregation(
                            match(Criteria.where("createdAt").lt(new Date(2022,11,01))),//<--- here you pass the month in question
                            project("createdAt").andExclude("_id"),
                               group().addToSet("createdAt").as("LATEST_DATES"),
                                unwind("LATEST_DATES"),
                                sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "LATEST_DATES"),
                                limit(1),//to get only one
                                project().andExclude("_id")
                        ),
                        "YOUR COLLECTION NAME",
                        DBObject.class
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like this :
First create a date of first day of current month.

```
firstDayOfCurrentMonth = LocalDate.now().withDayOfMonth(1))
```

then use it in query:

```
newAggregation(
      match(Criteria.where("createdAt").lt(firstDayOfCurrentMonth))),
      sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "createdAt"),
      limit(1)
    )
```

Comment: it's could be a solution,   but i wanna something similar to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69219451/mongodb-how-to-get-last-month-records)

Comment: ok, similar means you want mongo query, not java codes. because of `spring boot` tag, I thought you wanted `java`.